# Code Blocks show up as blank in gnome apps

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, slack

I've recently switched back to ubuntu desktop after 12 years or so on Mac. Everything is going great except for 1 bug that is *KILLING* me.

Anything formatted as a "code block" either doesn't display or show's up as invisible text. This happens in the Chrome and Brave browsers, and with the linux Slack desktop app whenever I or anyone else creates a "code or text snippet".

In the case of slack I know the text is there because I can see it formatted correctly on the ios client, and in the case of web pages with code block content, I can see it correctly in firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu ver: 18.04 factory Dell installed. There isn't any "code" to paste. It's slack messages that people have inserted "code or text snippets" into, and web pages that have quoted code in a code block. Here's an example:

https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=39153

About 1/3 down the page is a code block that doesn't display. It displays fine in firefox, and I can select the empty text and copy paste it into terminal to see it, but it shows up as white in the browser.

Comment: The code blocks display fine for me in Firefox and Chrome. For example, I can see, `define service{
use generic-service` etc. with the box marked as "CODE" and a link to "SELECT ALL" next to the word code. I am glad you solved the problem. Please accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 1):

OK well I temporarily solved my problem in 2 ways but it broke again the next day with slack.

For Brave/Chrome: Install the "Force Custom Fonts" extension and set the "Code/Fixed Width" font to font of your choice.

From slack support:
Code blocks not rendering text on Unbuntu unless you disable the font-family CSS property was the last update on findings.